# Raw Headers in MS Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007, email-headers

I'm developing an Outlook Add-In (2007, VBA), which is supposed to send the raw Internet Headers of a MailItem to a Server, which then does some processing. With raw I mean before they are decoded.

I am aware of the GetInetHeaders-Function, but is there a way to get the headers before they are decoded by Outlook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Outlook receives the message and decodes before it is saved and hence becomes visible through the Outlook Object Model or MAPI.

Why exactly do you need to do that?

Comment: It's how the server API is implemented at the moment. Currently the server receives a JSON object from Thunderbird, which adds the undecoded headers to the object, and then processes it. If it had been possible to construct the same object in Outlook as well, the server API and the Thunderbird plugin wouldn't have to be changed, now I guess that become necessary (although it's not much of an issue). Thanks for your reply!

Comment: What are these undecoded headers used for? Would it not be simpler to explicitly set the properties exposed by Outlook (e.g. MailItem.Subject etc.)?

Comment: well yes, you're right, that is exactly what I am going to do know, it'll work fine. It was only because the Thunderbird version of my Outlook Add-in sends the undecoded headers, and if Outlook could have done the same thing, we wouldn't have to change the Tunderbird Addon. That's actually a minor task, it just that I'm quite new to Outlook development, so I'm being curious about what Outlook can and what it can't.